# "How to recover a schema dropped after EXPDP without doing the impdp?

Tags: oracle, schema, recovery, datapump

I was playing - for my upcoming project- how to perform `expdp` and `impdp` on play environment which is two levels away from the test environment . So i did `expdp` with scott/tiger and exported the scott schema. However, out of curiosity, I dropped Scott schema from the database (expecting to do `impdp` in the same database) then I got a lot of errors and lost the Scott schema from the database.

Is there I was I can recover Scott schema from the dumpfile?

This is what I did:

1. `expdp scott/tiger schemas=scott directory=test_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp logfile=expdpscott.log`
2. `impdp scott/tiger schemas=scott directory=test_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp logfile=impdpscott.log`
   .
   .
   .
   then I got this:

   > Job "SCOTT"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" completed with 4 error(s) at 19:13:31"

   ... then I did:
3. `drop user Scott cascade;`

   and then
4. `impdp scott/tiger schemas=scott directory=test_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp logfile=impdpscott.log`

then I got this error:

> UDI-01017: operation generated ORACLE error 1017 ORA-01017: invalid
>   username/password; logon denied

... Now I realized that I did a stupid thing (which is good as a learner).

How can I get back or recover the dropped `scott` schema?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you posted which errors you got in step #2; maybe they were irrelevant.

Now, as you dropped Scott, connect as a privileged user (such as SYS) and **create** user Scott. Here's an example:

- check list of tablespaces in your database
- create user
- grant it some privileges

---

```
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USER_DATA
APEX
APEX_9695076087226093

7 rows selected.

SQL> create user littlefoot identified by lion
  2    default tablespace user_data
  3    temporary tablespace temp
  4    profile default
  5    quota  unlimited on user_data;

User created.

SQL>
SQL> grant create session       to littlefoot;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create table         to littlefoot;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create procedure     to littlefoot;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create sequence      to littlefoot;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create view          to littlefoot;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create trigger       to littlefoot;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Once you do that, run `IMPDP` once again.

Comment: i followed the step you put here and got thisORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-39087: directory name TEST_DIR is invalid